# glTF Are bone matrices specified in local or model space?

Tags: c++, json, animation, graphics, gltf

So the official documentation says:

> Note that the node transform is the local transform of the node relative to the joint, like any other node in the glTF node hierarchy as described in the Transformation section.

I am a bit fuzzy as to what exactly the distinction is between node and joint here.

Assuming I can conflate the 2, go to the `SimpleSkin` exmaple int the [models](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0) And look at the json:

```
 "nodes" : [ {
    "skin" : 0,
    "mesh" : 0
  }, {
    "children" : [ 2 ],
    "translation" : [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ]
  }, {
    "rotation" : [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]
  } ],

  "skins" : [ {
    "inverseBindMatrices" : 4,
    "joints" : [ 1, 2 ]
  } ],
```

joint 1 is the parent of joint 2. So if I treat that hierarchy like any other node hierarchy, the transform of node1 is to be applied to node 2 as well, given the values, at rest node 1 and node 2 rest in the same position.

But when you look at the diagrams for that example:

[image]

They are not in the same position. If, however you consider that the transforms are independent of each other (i.e that the transform of joint 1 does not affect joint 2), then joint 1 sits above joint 2, which is at minimum consistent with what the diagrams show (although not consistent with what the animation describes, since it's the top bone that should rotate and in this configuration it's the bottom one that will).

Comment: @emackey Sorry to poke but this is very confusing : P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man, you're finding all kinds of flaws in the tutorials.

In general yes, "node" and "joint" are the same thing, except they are indexed separately.  glTF 2.0 uses array index numbers as identification for many things, and there are pros and cons to that approach.  But in this case:

```
nodes: [ { node index 0 }, { node index 1 }, { node index 2 } ]
```

Followed by:

```
joints: [ 1, 2 ]
```

This means that joint index 0 is represented by node index 1, and joint 1 by node 2.  Every joint is a node, but not every node is a joint.  This becomes important when reading the `JOINTS_0` array, as those will be joint indices.  But more importantly, it is written this way because the `inverseBindMatrix` array has the same length as the joints array, so there is a 1:1 mapping guarantee there.

Let's talk about the jointMatrix for a minute.  The [tutorial's implementation section](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Tutorials/blob/master/gltfTutorial/gltfTutorial_020_Skins.md#vertex-skinning-implementation) has this bit of pseudocode:

```
jointMatrix(j) =
  globalTransformOfNodeThatTheMeshIsAttachedTo^-1 *
  globalTransformOfJointNode(j) *
  inverseBindMatrixForJoint(j);
```

But in case you're feeling a little burned by some of the pseudo-ness, here's the [corresponding block of code in the sample viewer](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Viewer/blob/d32ca25dc273c0b0982e29efcea01b45d0c85105/src/skin.js#L32-L36).  It basically amounts to:

```
jointMatrix[j] = skinnedNode.inverseWorldTransform * 
                 jointNode.worldTransform * inverseBindMatrix[j]
```

The nodes' transformations are relative to their parents, but the `inverseBindMatrix` part is specified relative to this glTF model's world.  So the host app needs to calculate the node's full transformation relative to glTF scene root, and the result of this calculation will change if any ancestor is animated.  Likewise we need to know the inverse of the full world transform for a different node, one that holds the mesh with the skin on it (apparently mis-labeled "parentNode" in the sample viewer, it should be called "skinnedNode" or similar, [see call site](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Viewer/blob/35df3ff146e88cc585401db546fb9ee3366607d2/src/renderer.js#L339)).

What does this do?  We need the "inverseWorldTransform" of the skinned node itself, in case some foolish artist has moved that node somewhere.  It needs to come back to the origin for these binding calculations.  We of course need the world transform of the joint's node itself, the actual bone, which may be animated or may have been moved by a parent joint's animation, or both.  And finally, we need the inverseBindMatrix for the joint, which if the joint hasn't moved itself away from the rest position, will cancel out the joint's position.  This all typically runs on the CPU, at most once per frame, or at least whenever the animation system or other outside force causes some joints to move.

Part of the problem being solved here is this:  The node that holds the skinned mesh may have a particular place in the scene hierarchy, and may have been moved somewhere.  The root of the skeleton might be a different node in the hierarchy, and could be elsewhere.  The vertex shader drawing the skinned mesh is trying to draw it where the skinned node says it should be, not where the skeleton root says it should be.  That's a problem.  We need to get out of the skin's location, get back to the origin, then go down to the joint's world location, and bind the joint there.  The results coming out of the vertex shader need to place the skin around the joints, at the joint's location, regardless of where the skinned node thought it was.

The glTF Validator will complain if you place a skinned mesh somewhere other than the root of a scene, with any kind of transform.  When a skin is in use, all of the location information comes from the joint locations, not the skin's location.  The skin's location is thrown away by including its world inverse in the above calculations.  So if the skinned node sits at the origin with no transform on it, that's a whole term you can optimize away from this equation.

But, many glTF models do include skins at non-root locations, so the inverse of the skinned mesh location is included because the vertex shader will be called from that location.  Each vertex will make its way over to where the joints actually are, and then further move itself by the difference between the joint's current position and the joint's rest position.

Comment: "Oh man, you're finding all kinds of flaws in the tutorials."
I have a talent for breaking things, I usually try to follow the path lesss travelled by, and that has made all the difference.

Comment: The explanation makes sense but doesn;t answer my main question. If the transform of the parent is applied to the child, then in the SImpleSkin example, both joints will be at the exact same location at rest. This doesn;t match the diagrams in the tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I think you're right and the tutorial is wrong.  Both joints are co-located.  The one that's in the wrong spot doesn't ever move or rotate, so the viewers never see it do the wrong thing.  All it has to do is hold its own vertices in place.

Comment: Filed: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Tutorials/issues/44

Comment: btw the wording was already fixed, as I tried to correct the table before :p

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the answer, this is what the bones are actually supposed to look like:

[image]

Comment: That's what the bones are actually doing, yes.  I'm sure the author intended the bones to be at different locations though.  He writes these sample models by hand, so he never saw this happening in Blender or anywhere.  Probably the `translate` just got put on the wrong node.

Comment: The official [glTF sample model repo](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/master/2.0/README.md) contains several non-hand-written, much more full-featured models, such as a Fox and some humanoid characters.  Give them a try since it looks like you've exhausted this particular sample.

Comment: Yes the goal is to get as many of them, the next one is the cylinder like bending one, then the animated dummys.