# Animation differences between my code and babylon, why?

Tags: c++, animation, math, graphics, gltf

I'm trying to render the glTF [RiggedSimple](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/RiggedSimple) sample model.

This is my code's result:
[image]

This is babylon's:
[image]

As you can see, in mine the model deforms, however in babylon it remains fairly rigid.

In my case I am not doing anything fancy, i shoving the skin matrices as defined in gltf directly to the GPU, so no quaternion skinning or similar techniques, just pure unadultered linear algebra.

Should I expect this result with regular matrices? Or is the difference in rendering due to a fault in my implementation?

Comment: Hm, looks like the center of rotation isn't correct in your implementation. Hard to say without seeing the code, but are you sure you've computed the jointMatrix array correctly? (See pseudocode in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64761383/836708))

Comment: I think I have a memory issue somewhere, I reran the code and now it works as in the exmaple. Although ASAN is not revealing anything. I might need to close this one until i have more info.

Comment: nvm, it seems the problem in the giff was that I was not applying the translation transforms in the animation.

Yup, that;s definitely it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct behavior of [RiggedSimple](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/RiggedSimple), rendered in the Blender viewport.

The parent bone has its origin at the bottom center, and the child bone has its own origin halfway up the model (shown with an orange dot in this case).  When the vertices at the top move, they move only due to rotation.  The center of rotation is always the associated bone's origin.

Note the vertices around that middle band barely move at all, but they do get nudged a little bit.  They too are being partially influenced by the child bone, so their movement is an orbit around the orange dot. The parent bone has a pretty good grip on them though, so they don't move far.

[image: Bones inside RiggedSimple]

Here are the joint weights, visualized in Blender.  On the left, the parent bone is at full strength (red) at the bottom, and has no influence (blue) at the top.  This bone doesn't move, and has pretty decent weight on the central band of vertices.

On the right, the child bone is visualized.  It's the one that has the rotation animation.  The roles are mostly reversed, as it has full strength at the top and zero strength at the bottom.  It has a very faint influence over the central vertices.

[image: Joint Weight visualization]

To get into this mode, first select the skinned mesh, and then switch to "Weight Paint" mode.  Use the "Vertex Groups" picker shown on the right to select a bone to view or edit its weights.  In glTF, it's recommended that not more than 4 separate bones have any influence over the same vertex, otherwise realtime renderers may have problems or not support it.  Also, it's important for the bone influences on each vertex to sum up to exactly 1.0 (100% total weight per vertex, not more or less).  Otherwise there could be problems, for example if two bones were both at 100% on a vertex and their vertex got a total of 200%, then a relocation of the whole skeleton would move that vertex twice as far away, and things would get terrible quickly. I think the Blender glTF exporter probably takes care of some of these concerns automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In my brilliance I commented out the translations in the animation while debugging and forgot to enable them. For this model the animation specifies a non negligible vertical translation. So it;s no surprise that the results are different.
[image]

Comment: The mesh looks good.  I'm not sure your yellow bone is shown in the correct location.  I think this bone's origin should be near the center of this model, between the two sections.  You can see that's the area that looks like the center of rotation for the top of the model.

Comment: Yes, there was a small error in the shader I use to render the bones. It is now where you say it should be